# Creating a unit to input an array of different computers display/sound and output only 1 with a switch to select

Tags: microcontroller, computers, monitor

I have a few computers and I was wondering if there was an inexpensive way to link them all to a box that I would be able to use to select which ones I want outputted to my monitor(s).

I've only really had experience with an arduino, but is there some kind of microcontroller that I would be able to use to handle this?  It would be nice if I could hook up multiple monitors for it to work with (say I want to use two monitors while working on one of the computers).

Answer (score 2):

There are commerically-available devices called Keyboard/Video/Mouse (KVM) switches that probably do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a lot like a KVM (Keyboard, Video, Mouse) switch.

You run keyboard, video, and mouse cables for each computer to the switch, and you cable one keyboard, one monitor, and one mouse to the switch.  You then turn (or flip) the front-panel switch, and the keyboard, monitor, and mouse are connected to the selected computer.

They're commercially available, and last time I looked they were cheap.